# Ethereum Smat Contract Blocking

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Can Ethereum's Validator execute several Smart Contracts at the same time? Or it can not make any other operation if started the execution?

Comment: are you trying to scale Ethereum? forget it. Even Vitalik himself can't do it, even with his Ethereum 2.0 upgrade it wont scale.

Comment: each contract is executed sequentially, meaning that the number 1 smart contract platform of the Word is running on a single computer (a computer with computing power equivalent to hardware produced 20 year ago, except for the SSD disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since transactions from a block or pool are executed sequentially, and a transaction can only refer to one smart contract, the EVM executes only one smart contract at a time (while internal calls from it are possible).

А в чем собственно проблема? :-)